# Highest Matches as an umpire

Tags: mysql, sql

Their are two column umpire1 and umpire 2.

I need to find the name of the umpire who attend maximum matches doesn't matter he is umpire1 or umpire2 in that match his occurrence should count.

for e.g-- S Ravi

```
37 time as umpire1
57 time as umpire2
94 -- total
```

Output like

Umpire   Total_count

```
S Ravi       94
```

Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`level`' given input columns:
line 2 pos 14;
'Aggregate [umpire1#2497], [umpire1#2497, 'sum(CASE WHEN ('level = S Ravi) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS u1#2464, 'sum(CASE WHEN ('level = SJ Davis) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS u2#2465, 'sum(('u1 + 'u2)) AS total#2466]

```
select umpire1,
sum(case when level ='umpire1' then 1 else 0 end) as u1,
sum(case when level ='umpire2' then 1 else 0 end) as u2,
sum(u1+u2) as total
from IPL_MATCHES group by umpire1;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  This information is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to find the name of the umpire who attend maximum matches doesn't matter he is umpire1 or umpire2 in that match his occurrence should count.

I think `umpire1` and `umpire2` are two columns in your table and you want to unpivot and count:

```
select umpire, count(*)
from ((select umpire1 as umpire from ipl_matches
      ) union all
      (select umpire2 as umpire from ipl_matches
      )
     ) u
group by umpire;
```

If you want the umpire with the most matches, then add:

```
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Thankyou this works for me can you tell me where we use unpivot in sql

Comment: @Jatin07 . . . (1) That is irrelevant to this question.  (2) MySQL doesn't have specific syntax for unpivoting.  (3) The `union all` approach is fine for this purpose.

Comment: FWIW, I think that there are more parentheses here than is strictly necessary